# How to return Data from readFileAsync

Tags: node.js, json, async-await, fs

I have a function that needs to read from a file, then convert it to an json object with JSON.parse(string) and lastly return it to be used elsewhere.

this object is written to a txt file using JSON.stringify():

```
let User = {
    Username:"#",
    Password:"#",
    FilePaths:[
        {Year:'#', Month:'#', FileName:'#'}
    ]
}
```

the writing works fine, my problem is the reading,
Here is my code:

```
const readFileAsync = promisify(fs.readFile);
async function GetUserData(User) {
    const Read = async () => {
        return await (await readFileAsync('UserData\\'+User.Username+'\\UserData.txt')).toString();        
    }    
    return Read().then(data=>{return JSON.parse(data)})
}

console.log(GetUserData(User));
```

The result I get back is :

```
Promise {[[PromiseState]]: 'pending', [[PromiseResult]]: undefined}
```

How can I make this work so

Comment: Have you tried: `console.log(await GetUserData(User));` ?

Comment: Yes, I get the error ```Uncaught c:\#\#\#\UserDataHandler.js:59
console.log(await GetUserData(User));
            ^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list ```

Comment: You have forgot one `)`. But this error is not related with `async/await`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, `GetUserData` returns a promise, so you'll need to use `.then` to get the data once resolved.

```
GetUserData(User).then(data => {
  // do something with data
});
```

Alternatively, `fs` has a sync function you can use, rather relying on `readFile` (which is async), use [readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options). Usage below:

```
function GetUserData(User) {
    const data = fs.readFileSync('UserData\\'+User.Username+'\\UserData.txt').toString();

    return JSON.parse(data);
}

console.log(GetUserData(User));
```